# Check network connectivity

Tags: bash

```
if [[ `ping -c1 8.8.8.8 | grep "100%" | wc -l` = 1 ]]
```

This helps me to check whether there is a problem on the internet connection, because:

```
ping -c1 8.8.8.8 | grep "100%"
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

ping -c1 8.8.8.8 | grep "100%" | wc -l
1
```

But it doesn't help when I get

```
ping -c1 8.8.8.8 | grep "100%" | wc -l
connect: Network is unreachable
0
```

So I did:

```
ping -c1 8.8.8.8 | grep "100%|unreachable" | wc -l
connect: Network is unreachable
0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The error message is going to stderr and not stdout. Either add `2>/dev/null` to redirect stderr output to the null device and suppress its output, or add `2>&1` to redirect stderr to stdout and combine the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than relying on the textual output from ping to tell you if the network is unreachable, a better mechanism would be to rely on the exit status.

```
ping -c1 -q 8.8.8.8
status=$?;
case $status in
    0)
        echo "host is alive";
    ;;
    1)
        echo "network unreachable or host not responding to pings";
    ;;
    2)
        echo "No route to host or other error";
    ;;
esac
```

Note: In my experience, ping alone is quite slow and cumbersome. If you're looking to get a fast understanding of whether a network is alive or not, especially from within a script, I'd look at `fping` which gives you the same results only faster :-)

Comment: The single `;` as you've used it in this code is just not necessary in `bash`.

Comment: Probably not but it's my preferred style. Actually the mistake is that I didn't put one on the line beginning `ping -c1 ...`

Answer (score -1):

This solution worked when I tested it:

```
res=$(ping -c1 8.8.8.8)
echo "$res" | grep "100%" | wc -l &&
echo "$res" | grep "unreachable" | wc -l &&
echo 'Connection good!'
```

Comment: It doesn't even remotely do what you hope it does.